# app.dart error when trying to navigate to new page using ontap

Tags: dart, flutter

I am using Fontawesome icons to navigate to a new page in flutter using ontap and im getting a strange error in app.dart.

Im pretty new to dart so my debugging skills arent revealing anything. Here is ontap code.

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new MaterialApp(
  theme: new ThemeData(
    fontFamily: "Tahoma",
    brightness: Brightness.light,
    primaryColor: Colors.grey, //Changing this will change the color of the TabBar
    accentColor: Colors.cyan[600],
  ),
 routes: routes,
 home: DefaultTabController(
 length: 1,
  child: Scaffold(
  appBar: new LBAppBar().getAppBar(),
  drawer: new LBDrawer().getDrawer(),
    body: Column(children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            //ROW 1
            children: [
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
                child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
           GestureDetector(
                     child: Icon(
                     FontAwesomeIcons.solidCheckSquare,
                     size: 60.0,
                     color: const Color.fromRGBO(1,89,99, 1.0),
             ),
                  onTap: () {
                         Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/checkin');
                          }),
                Text("Check In", style: new TextStyle( color: Color.fromRGBO(1,89,99, 1.0), fontWeight: FontWeight.bold ))
],
 ),
```

Im trying to navigate to a new dart file where i will capture a userid and collect information in a form but I cant get it to navigate to the new page.

---- ROUTES CODE ---

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../screens/index.dart';
import '../screens/checkin.dart';

final routes = {
 '/index':         (BuildContext context) => new Index(),
 '/checkin':       (BuildContext context) => new CheckIn(),
 };
```

Here is the error.

The following assertion was thrown building MaterialApp(dirty, state: _MaterialAppState#6ff5c): 'package:flutter/src/widgets/app.dart': Failed assertion: line 169 pos 15: 'navigatorObservers != null': is not true.

I have a routes.dart file with the checkin route listed.

Comment: Include your routes: routes code also. how you have set var routes

Answer (score 0):

did you provide routes to your top-level app widget(meterialApp, cupertinoApp, widgetsApp)?

Navigator is only built of you have provided any routes.id you are creating widgets on the go or you needs any parameaters you can use

`Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => Widget())),`

Comment: Routes are included. I’m wondering if ontap is the issue , I’m using onpressed in the same way and it’s working

Comment: can you include whole code it would help me answer your question in a better way

Comment: Yes I’ll post the full dart file for both routes and index.dart

Comment: I added routes.dart code. I tried removing the defualttabcontroller because im not using it but that didnt work. Whats confusing me is the code is exactly the same on my login page the only difference is the onTap VS onpressed on the button.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, multiple material apps declared . I reduced it to one and it’s working now